# Application crashes with objects created in loop using Luabind in C++

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

I'm trying to use Lua with my game engine prototype but I'm stuck with odd error.

My target is to create X objects in loop with Lua and render them.

```
sprite = Sprite("icon.jpg", 300, 300, 0)
sprite2 = Sprite("icon.jpg", 100, 100, 0)

b1 = BoxObject(sprite)
b2 = BoxObject(sprite2)

sprite3 = Sprite("circle.png", 200, 100, 0)
sprite4 = Sprite("circle.png", 300, 100, 0)

b3 = CircleObject(sprite3)
b4 = CircleObject(sprite4)

n = Node()
n:AddChild(b1)
n:AddChild(b2)
n:AddChild(b3)
n:AddChild(b4)

for i = 0, 10, 1 do 
    x = math.random(700)
    y = math.random(500)
    n:AddChild(BoxObject(Sprite("icon.jpg", x, y, 0)))
end

for i = 0, 10, 1 do 
    x = math.random(700)
    y = math.random(500)
    local s = Sprite("circle.png", x, y, 0)
    local o = CircleObject(s)
    n:AddChild(BoxObject)
end
```

If I do it this way, code works without errors, but game crashes in random time from instant to few secs. If I use this code with only objects created in loops, not those created manually, game crashes instantly.

However if I write Lua code equivalent in C++, it runs without any problem.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    float x = rand() % 700;
    float y = rand() % 500;

    n->AddChild(new BoxObject(new Sprite("icon.jpg", x, y)));
}

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    float x = rand() % 700;
    float y = rand() % 500;

    n->AddChild(new CircleObject(new Sprite("circle.png", x, y)));
}
```

This is my Lua binding

```
static void Lua(lua_State *lua){
    luabind::module(lua)
    [
     luabind::class_<Node>("Node")
     .def(luabind::constructor<>())
     .def(luabind::constructor<float, float, float>())
     .def("Render", &Node::Render)
     .def("Move", &Node::Move)
     .def("Rotate", &Node::Rotate)
     .def("AddChild", &Node::AddChild)
     .def("RotateAroundPoint", &Node::RotateAroundPoint)
     ];
}
```

Every method accepts and returns void except AddChild

```
virtual void AddChild(Node *child);
```

Sprite and Box aand Circle Objects are inherited from Node class.

Does any one have an idea what can cause this odd error? I would be glad for any help.

Comment: It looks like objects created in loops act like local variables. If I change, for example, sprite3 to local sprite3, it crashes same way after some time. So maybe it is just my misunderstanding of Lua.

Comment: "n:AddChild(BoxObject)", isn't BoxObject a function?

Comment: No, BoxObject is class inherited from Node (same as Sprite) for handling Box2D objects and Sprite is given to it via constructor as it's graphical representance.

Answer (score 1):

You have serious ownership problems.

In C/C++, a piece of code "owns" a pointer or other resource if that code or object takes on the responsibility for destroying it. It keeps it alive while it needs it, and it ensures that it is destroyed when *it* is finished using it.

Maintaining an understanding of who owns what is vital for any even mildly complex C or C++ program.

When Luabind creates a C++ object *from Lua*, then the Lua script *owns* that object. This means that Lua's garbage collector will decide when to delete it.

So this:

```
local s = Sprite("circle.png", x, y, 0)
```

Will create a `Sprite` object who's lifetime is governed by the Lua state. When the Lua state no longer has any active references to it, then the Lua state will be free to delete it.

I don't know how your code works, but this line:

```
local o = CircleObject(s)
```

Suggests that `CircleObject`'s constructor is supposed to claim ownership over the object it is given (thus the `CircleObject` decides when to delete it). If that's true, then you need to actually state that when you bind this constructor with Luabind.

If `CircleObject`'s constructor is not supposed to take ownership, then... well, quite frankly your design is suspect; long-term storage of a pointer that you don't own is just begging for something to get screwed up. But if it's really supposed to store a pointer that's owned by someone else, then you need to use Lua mechanisms to ensure that the `Sprite` remains alive so long as `CircleObject` does.

Similarly, the `Node::AddChild` function looks like it's claiming ownership of whatever node it is given. This would be done like this:

```
.def("AddChild", &Node::AddChild, adopt(_1))
```

The `_1` means the first parameter of the function. This means that the `Node` claims ownership of the first parameter; if it's owned by Lua, this ownership chain is now broken, and C++ now owns the object.

Personally, I would say that this API is... not good for Lua. You seem to want all of the minor object ownership to be done in C++ code. So Lua should call C++ functions that set all of these minor objects up without Lua having to interfere. Lua should call a member function of a `NodeManager` in order to get/create a `Node`, then it should call a function that will create a `Sprite` within that `Node`.

Lua shouldn't have to deal with the minutiae of `BoxObject` and such. It shouldn't have to directly create a `Sprite` object and put it into a `Node`.

Also, again personally, this API is not good for *C++* either. If `Sprite` needs to be stored in some kind of container, and that container needs to be stored in some kind of `Node`, then it should not be possible to create a `Sprite` *without* storing it in a container. This is what factory functions are for. I'm not even sure what `BoxObject` and `CircleObject` are for, since `Sprite` seems to be doing all the work.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem -- another way to deal with the ownership issues is to use smart pointers. Consider boost's shared_ptr, or the c++11 equivalent. Using shared ptr's will keep the lua garbage collector from releasing the object at inopportune times. The luabind docs cover the changes to your code needed to make this work.

Comment: Thanks for great answer. I thought it should be ownership problem between Lua and C++. Those local variables in Lua script were just my tests I forget to delete. I've just tryed to add adopt(_1) to my Lua bindings, but compiller screams it doesn't know adopt. And for my C++ API. Sprite doesn't need to be stored in Node's child list. It can be handled alone (it inherits from Node, so it can have it's own childs too), but I use one main Node for simpler rendering. It's better to call Node::Render() than calling it over every Sprite. And BoxObject and CircleObject are classes for Box2D objects.

Comment: Ok, I was missing some Luabind headers, but now it generates errors with Luabind adopt_policy. But I will think about using managers for creating objects.